# Apache Spark - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

Tags: python, mysql, docker, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to submit Apache Spark driver program to the remote cluster. I'm having difficulties with the python package called `mysql`. I installed this package on all Spark nodes. Cluster is running inside docker-compose, images are based on [bde2020](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark/tree/52647ef7c61305e904b2627534553ce4806e23c4).

```sh
$ docker-compose logs  impressions-agg
impressions-agg_1  | Submit application /app/app.py to Spark master spark://spark-master:7077
impressions-agg_1  | Passing arguments 
impressions-agg_1  | 19/11/13 18:45:20 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
impressions-agg_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
impressions-agg_1  |   File "/app/app.py", line 6, in <module>
impressions-agg_1  |     from mysql.connector import connect
impressions-agg_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
impressions-agg_1  | log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
impressions-agg_1  | log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
impressions-agg_1  | log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Module `mysql` is installed via pip on all nodes.

```sh
$ docker-compose exec spark-master pip list
Package         Version            
--------------- -------------------
mysql-connector 2.2.9              
pip             18.1               
setuptools      40.8.0.post20190503

$ docker-compose exec spark-worker pip list
Package         Version            
--------------- -------------------
mysql-connector 2.2.9              
pip             18.1               
setuptools      40.8.0.post20190503
```

How can I solve this?
Thank you for any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the node has mysql installed, the *container* does not. What the logs are telling you is that `impressions-agg_1` contains a script at `/app/app.py` which is trying to load mysql but cannot find it.

Did you create `impressions-agg_1`? Add a `RUN pip install mysql` step to its Dockerfile.

Comment: Yes this was a problem, the container had installed "mysql" but for python2 & driver was submitted with python3... pip3 install ... solved the problem. Thank you.